# Compositing alpha like in Gimp

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency

I have a problem to compose two pictures: one is a background picture, the other one is a picture made out of a RenderLayer in which I disabled the "sky" parameter to get an alpha channel. The idea is that I'd like to put the second picture on top of the first picture, like I'd do in Gimp. I tried to use several kind of nodes to do that (Alpha over, Mix, Alpha Convert...), but none of them do exactly what I want.

**Steps to reproduce the problem**

- First, on the default view with the cube, just do `space`/`quick smoke`
- Then, in the cube Physics tab, change the color of the smoke to red, and press `Alt+A` twice to produce some smoke
- In the RenderLayer tab, disable the "sky" option
- Go in the Compositing layout, and add as input this picture:
  [image]
- Combine this picture with the render layer by using an "alpha over" node :
  [image]

Problem: If you carefully look at the RenderLayer part, you will see that the top corner of the cube is hidden by the smoke. However after the compositing, the corner becomes visible, like if the alpha chosen by Blender was not the "good" alpha...

What I'd like: produce the same render as the one generated by Gimp for example when I save the output of the RenderLayer:

[image]

NB: For people that want it, here is the picture I get when I save the RenderLayer:
[image]

Thank you!

NB: I cannot just do manual post processing because I want to do it for a whole movie.

Comment: Did you click on the Convert Premultiply toggle on the Alpha Over node?

Comment: Yes I tried everything I had in mind, including this, and also I tried to add some "Convert Alpha" nodes, without any success.

Comment: I guess you could add a curve node to the alpha channel and make it a bit more dense?

Comment: Well it's quite dirty, sometime I want to have exactly the same result as the one I would get with most programs… And it's not the first time I have this problem, I tried once to include a png into a video and it was not possible to do it properly…

Comment: But can you explain why there is a difference ?

Comment: Actually GIMP result is wrong. You're probably more used to that kind of result because many applications (including web browsers and many bitmap editing softwares) blend images non-linearly.
Blender renders linear images which produce a result closer to reality when blended together with the alpha over operation (that means no dark fringes), while GIMP being currently a sRGB-only program blends two non-linear images together, which produces a dark fringe when mixing certain colours together, hence the denser appearance on the second mix.

Comment: If you really want to mimic GIMP's behavior, it is possible withing Blender's compositor using a couple of gamma 2.2 nodes for both images before the alpha over node, then an extra gamma (1/2.2) node after the mix in order to invert the result, back to linear.
Your blends will be no longer correct, but they will look closer to what GIMP produces.